# Should off-topic or poor quality posts be deleted immediately?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, best-practices, deleted-posts

I often encounter an off-topic or otherwise unsuitable post, and comment so on the post. The OP might immediately reply asking for the best course of action.

Should I tell the OP to delete the question? Should I leave it to those who have moderation powers?

If I were to leave the question, they might receive an answer and my judgement may be proven incorrect.

If I were to tell them to delete immediately, their post would not be seen by most of the community.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.

- If you're sure the question is really off topic for the site, just flag or vote to close, and recommend the OP to delete before downvotes are cast, possibly telling what site to post in, if any.
- If the question can be improved do your best to improve it yourself, if possible, or if the problem is the logic of the question itself, ask the OP to clarify, guiding them as much as possible.
- If the question can't be improved in your opinion but you're not 100% sure just move on, and let others decide. Better not post a comment in this situation, since you can't really help. If you feel it's of poor quality cast a downvote to indicate this for others, and if you really care visit the question again at some point to see if it got improved, in which case you can undo the downvote.